# .htaccess mod_rewrite problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just recently ported over my source code to Ubuntu Server from Windows and I've been having a few .htaccess mod_rewrite problems.  I have mod_rewrite enabled for Apache.  Here is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^css/default/?$ css/default.css
RewriteRule ^user/?$ user.php
RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ user.php?username=$1
```

Here are some examples of the problems that I'm having. For some reason, I can access

```
http://localhost/css/default
```

with no problem, but when I do

```
http://localhost/css/default/
```

it cannot find it.  Also, accessing

```
http://localhost/user/hunter101/
```

doesn't seem to register hunter101 as a GET anymore... any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some conflicts with [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) as your URL and files have a very similar name. Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: interesting...  nice inspecting Gumbo :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you escape the forward slash?

```
RewriteRule ^user\/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\/?$ user.php?username=$1
```

I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mod_rewrite doesn't need forward slashes to be escaped.

Comment: Furthermore for the sake of completeness: Shouldn’t the first slash not be escaped too?